# CSS grid wrapping

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is it possible to make a CSS grid wrap without using media queries?

In my case, I have a non-deterministic number of items that I want placed in a grid and I want that grid to wrap. Using Flexbox, I'm unable to reliably space things nicely. I'd like to avoid a bunch of media queries too.

Here's [some sample code](https://codepen.io/kentcdodds/pen/MpZKgx):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 186px 186px 186px 186px;
}

.grid > * {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

And here's a GIF image:

[image: GIF image of what I'm seeing]

As a side-note, if anyone can tell me how I could avoid specifying the width of all the items like I am with `grid-template-columns` that would be great. I'd prefer the children to specify their own width.

Answer (score 505, accepted):

Use either [`auto-fill`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-repeat-auto-fill) or [`auto-fit`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-repeat-auto-fit) as the first argument of the [`repeat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#funcdef-repeat) notation.

[`<auto-repeat>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#typedef-auto-repeat) variant of the `repeat()` notation:

```
repeat( [ auto-fill | auto-fit ] , [ <line-names>? <fixed-size> ]+ <line-names>? )
```

---

### `auto-fill`

> When `auto-fill` is given as the repetition number, if the grid
> container has a [definite](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#definite) size or max size in the relevant axis, then
> the number of repetitions is the largest possible positive integer
> that does not cause the grid to overflow its grid container.
>
> <sup>*https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-repeat-auto-fill*</sup>

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 186px);
}

.grid>* {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

The grid will repeat as many tracks as possible without overflowing its container.

[image: Using auto-fill as the repetition number of the repeat() notation]

In this case, given the example above *(see image)*, only 5 tracks can fit the grid-container without overflowing. There are only 4 items in our grid, so a fifth one is created as an empty track within the remaining space.

The rest of the remaining space, track #6, ends the explicit grid. This means there was not enough space to place another track.

---

### `auto-fit`

> The `auto-fit` keyword behaves the same as `auto-fill`, except
> that after [grid item placement](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#auto-placement-algo) any empty repeated tracks are collapsed.
>
> <sup>*https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-repeat-auto-fit*</sup>

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 186px);
}

.grid>* {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

The grid will still repeat as many tracks as possible without overflowing its container, but the empty tracks will be collapsed to `0`.

A collapsed track is treated as having a fixed track sizing function of `0px`.

[image: Using auto-fit as the repetition number of the repeat() notation]

Unlike the `auto-fill` image example, the empty fifth track is collapsed, ending the explicit grid right after the 4th item.

---

### `auto-fill` vs `auto-fit`

The difference between the two is noticeable when the [`minmax()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-grid-template-columns-minmax) function is used.

Use `minmax(186px, 1fr)` to range the items from `186px` to a [fraction of the leftover space in the grid container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#fr-unit).

When using `auto-fill`, the items will grow once there is no space to place empty tracks.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(186px, 1fr));
}

.grid>* {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

When using `auto-fit`, the items will grow to fill the remaining space because all the empty tracks will be collapsed to `0px`.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(186px, 1fr));
}

.grid>* {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

---

Playground:

### [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rickyruiz/pen/KemeoX)

Inspecting auto-fill tracks

[image: auto-fill]

---

Inspecting auto-fit tracks

[image: auto-fit]

Comment: Is there any way to make it center the ones that are on the next line?

Comment: Just like you would with flex box, on the `display: grid` element use `justify-content: center`

Comment: Dear @Ricky How to make it so that the first property of minmax, eg. `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(186px, 1fr));` is not pixels, but just as long as the div has text inside?

Comment: @mesqueeb It is not possible, a [definite](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#definite) size is needed. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334006/4305494) answer for more details.

Comment: Is there any way to make it so that when it has to go to the next line, two of the items go down instead of only one? So like from 4 to 2 to 1 and not have it 4 to 3 to 2 to 1?

Comment: Is it possible to do the similar wrapping in height. I mean, as soon as 1 reaches viewport height, the data inside 1 wraps to 2 and so on..similar to sine curve?

Comment: Re *"range the items from 186px to 186px..."* can be read as a range of zero (if the following is not parsed). Perhaps rephrase?

Comment: @Spittal, I tried `justify-content: center`, but it doesn't work as expected. https://codepen.io/helloCaptMomo/pen/MWoJpqz do you have any advice?

Comment: is there a way to use `grid-column: span` with `auto-fill` or `auto-fit`?

Comment: I might be missing something here but the original question was about how to make the items wrap (to next line?). the accepted solution only changes the width of the columns I don't see any wrapping...

Comment: Is it possible to define the max number of columns that a row can have without setting the column width?

Comment: So many years after you wrote this, but still quite helpful. Thanks for the thoroughness and specially the to-the-point comparison between `auto-fill` and `auto-fit` with illustrations. Could not have hoped for better.

Comment: What if you don't want all columns to have the same width?

Answer (score 24):

You want either `auto-fit` or `auto-fill` inside the `repeat()` function:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 186px);
```

The difference between the two becomes apparent if you also use a `minmax()` to allow for flexible column sizes:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(186px, 1fr));
```

This allows your columns to flex in size, ranging from 186 pixels to equal-width columns stretching across the full width of the container. `auto-fill` will create as many columns as will fit in the width. If, say, five columns fit, even though you have only four grid items, there will be a fifth empty column:

[image]

Using `auto-fit` instead will prevent empty columns, stretching yours further if necessary:

[image]

Comment: How can I do the exact opposite of "ranging from 186 pixels to equal-width columns" - i.e. I want it to auto-fit equal-width columns ranging *upto* a max of 186px wide columns? -

Answer (score 18):

You may be looking for `auto-fill`:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 186px);
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/wJRMox

To use up the available space more efficiently, you could use `minmax`, and pass in `auto` as the second argument:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(186px, auto));
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/jBXWLR

If you don't want the empty columns, you could use `auto-fit` instead of `auto-fill`.

Comment: Is there any way to make it center the ones that are on the next line?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation. On top of what you did, I wanted to center my columns in the container while not allowing empty columns to for them left or right:

```
.grid { 
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, auto));
}
```

Comment: Re *"while not allowing empty columns to for them"*: Do you mean *"while not allowing empty columns **either** for them"* (*to* → *[too](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/too#Adverb)* → *either*)? Or *"while not allowing empty columns for them"* (without *to*)? Or something else (it doesn't seem to compute)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a calendar example which is a common layout with lots of elements.  I show the 7 days in a week in `all-days` with `grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1.5em);` for the CSS and then only have to put the correct number of blanks at the start of each `all-days`
I left it at 4 "fake months" as more would just be excess HTML.

```css
.parent-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr);
}

.actions {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

.calendar-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 13em);
  justify-content: center;
}

.calendar-month {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1.5em;
  border: solid 1px green;
  place-items: center;
}

.calendar-month .all-days {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1.5em);
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
  place-items: center;
}

.no {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 1.5em;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="calendar-container">
    <div class="calendar-month">
      <div class="actions">
        <button>Next</button>
        <span>January</span> <button>Last</button>
      </div>
      <div class="all-days">
        <span class="no">1</span>
        <span class="no">2</span>
        <span class="no">3</span>
        <span class="no">4</span>
        <span class="no">5</span>
        <span class="no">6</span>
        <span class="no">7</span>
        <span class="no">8</span>
        <span class="no">9</span>
        <span class="no">10</span>
        <span class="no">11</span>
        <span class="no">12</span>
        <span class="no">13</span>
        <span class="no">14</span>
        <span class="no">15</span>
        <span class="no">16</span>
        <span class="no">17</span>
        <span class="no">18</span>
        <span class="no">19</span>
        <span class="no">20</span>
        <span class="no">21</span>
        <span class="no">22</span>
        <span class="no">23</span>
        <span class="no">24</span>
        <span class="no">25</span>
        <span class="no">26</span>
        <span class="no">27</span>
        <span class="no">29</span>
        <span class="no">30</span>
        <span class="no">31</span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-month">
      <div class="actions">
        <span>February</span>
      </div>
      <div class="all-days">
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no">1</span>
        <span class="no">2</span>
        <span class="no">3</span>
        <span class="no">4</span>
        <span class="no">5</span>
        <span class="no">6</span>
        <span class="no">7</span>
        <span class="no">8</span>
        <span class="no">9</span>
        <span class="no">10</span>
        <span class="no">11</span>
        <span class="no">12</span>
        <span class="no">16</span>
        <span class="no">13</span>
        <span class="no">14</span>
        <span class="no">15</span>
        <span class="no">16</span>
        <span class="no">17</span>
        <span class="no">18</span>
        <span class="no">19</span>
        <span class="no">20</span>
        <span class="no">21</span>
        <span class="no">22</span>
        <span class="no">23</span>
        <span class="no">24</span>
        <span class="no">25</span>
        <span class="no">26</span>
        <span class="no">27</span>
        <span class="no">28</span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-month">
      <div class="actions">
        <span>Bearanary</span>
      </div>
      <div class="all-days">
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no">1</span>
        <span class="no">2</span>
        <span class="no">3</span>
        <span class="no">4</span>
        <span class="no">6</span>
        <span class="no">7</span>
        <span class="no">8</span>
        <span class="no">9</span>
        <span class="no">10</span>
        <span class="no">11</span>
        <span class="no">12</span>
        <span class="no">13</span>
        <span class="no">14</span>
        <span class="no">15</span>
        <span class="no">16</span>
        <span class="no">17</span>
        <span class="no">18</span>
        <span class="no">19</span>
        <span class="no">20</span>
        <span class="no">21</span>
        <span class="no">22</span>
        <span class="no">23</span>
        <span class="no">24</span>
        <span class="no">25</span>
        <span class="no">26</span>
        <span class="no">27</span>
        <span class="no">29</span>
        <span class="no">30</span>
        <span class="no">31</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-month">
      <div class="actions">
        <span>Fishly</span>
      </div>
      <div class="all-days">
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no">1</span>
        <span class="no">2</span>
        <span class="no">3</span>
        <span class="no">4</span>
        <span class="no">6</span>
        <span class="no">7</span>
        <span class="no">8</span>
        <span class="no">9</span>
        <span class="no">10</span>
        <span class="no">11</span>
        <span class="no">12</span>
        <span class="no">13</span>
        <span class="no">14</span>
        <span class="no">15</span>
        <span class="no">16</span>
        <span class="no">17</span>
        <span class="no">18</span>
        <span class="no">19</span>
        <span class="no">20</span>
        <span class="no">21</span>
        <span class="no">22</span>
        <span class="no">23</span>
        <span class="no">24</span>
        <span class="no">25</span>
        <span class="no">26</span>
        <span class="no">27</span>
        <span class="no">29</span>
        <span class="no">30</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

Here's my attempt. *Excuse the fluff,* I was feeling extra creative.

My method is a parent `div` with **fixed** **dimensions**. The rest is just fitting the content inside that div accordingly.

This will **rescale** the images regardless of the aspect ratio. There will be **no hard cropping** either.

```css
body {
    background: #131418;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.my-image-parent {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px; /* Should match your div height */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}

/* Start demonstration background fluff */
    .bg1 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/801/799);}
    .bg2 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/799/800);}
    .bg3 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/800/799);}
    .bg4 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/801/801);}
    .bg5 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/802/800);}
    .bg6 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/800/802);}
    .bg7 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/802/802);}
    .bg8 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/803/800);}
    .bg9 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/800/803);}
    .bg10 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/803/803);}
    .bg11 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/803/799);}
    .bg12 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/799/803);}
    .bg13 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/806/799);}
    .bg14 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/805/799);}
    .bg15 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/798/804);}
    .bg16 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/804/799);}
    .bg17 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/804/804);}
    .bg18 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/799/804);}
    .bg19 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/798/803);}
    .bg20 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/803/797);}
/* end demonstration background fluff */

.my-image {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg1"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg2"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg3"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg4"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg5"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg6"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg7"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg8"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg9"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg10"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg11"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg12"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg13"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg14"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg15"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg16"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg17"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg18"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg19"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-image-parent">
    <div class="my-image bg20"></div>
</div>
```