# minmax fails (invalid property value)

Tags: css, css-grid

Chrome gives an `invalid property value` and doesn't respect the CSS:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(auto, 1fr));
```

It also fails when `auto` is replaced with `min-content` and `max-content`.

It works as expected when `auto` is replaced by a fixed value e.g.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

This is surprising because both `repeat` and `minmax` support the keywords.

The html is simple

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(auto, 1fr));
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When using `auto-fill` or `auto-fit`, there must be a definite min-size or max-size.

By "definite", the spec means:

> A size that can be determined without measuring content.
>
> <sup>*https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#definite*</sup>

When you set both `minmax` arguments to content-based size, like this:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(auto, 1fr));
```

... that's a violation of the spec because there is no definite size.

Using `min-content` and `max-content` would result in the same error for the same reason.

As long as one value is definite, and the first value is not `fr` (see below), the rule is valid.

> [**7.2.2.2. Repeat-to-fill: `auto-fill` and `auto-fit`
>   repetitions**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-repeat)
>
> When `auto-fill` is given as the repetition number, if the grid
>   container has a [**definite**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#definite) size or max size in the relevant axis, then the number of repetitions is the
>   largest possible positive integer that does not cause the grid to
>   overflow its grid container (treating each track as its max track
>   sizing function if that is definite or as its minimum track sizing
>   function otherwise, and taking `grid-gap` into account).
>
> If any number of repetitions would overflow, then 1 repetition.
>
> Otherwise, if the grid container has a definite min size in the relevant axis, the number of repetitions is the smallest possible positive integer that fulfills that minimum requirement.
>
> Otherwise, the specified track list repeats only once.

Comment: Got it; thanks for the informative and timely answer.  