# css grid property value invalid

Tags: css, css-grid

In both Chrome and Firefox nightly I get the following error when setting this property:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill);
grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
```

`Invalid property value`

When looking at the [repeat()](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#repeat-syntax) syntax it seems that I entered it correctly? Both browsers still seem to somehow make it work, but it seems odd I'd get an error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45333922/3597276

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that **[`repeat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#funcdef-repeat)** requires **two** arguments (meaning `repeat(auto-fill)` is invalid), along with `auto-repeat` (either `auto-fill` or `auto-fit`) requiring a **definite** track size:

> The `<auto-repeat>` variant can repeat automatically to fill a space, but requires definite track sizes so that the number of repetitions can be calculated. It can only appear once in the track list, but the same track list can also contain `<fixed-repeat>`s.

And a **[definite value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#definite)** is defined as:

> A size that can be determined without performing layout; that is, a `<length>`, a measure of text (without consideration of line-wrapping), a size of the initial containing block, or a `<percentage>` or other formula (such the “stretch-fit” sizing of non-replaced blocks [CSS2]) that is resolved solely against definite sizes.

As such, `repeat(auto-fill, 1fr)` is invalid, but `repeat(auto-fill, 100px)` is valid.