# Reproduce flex's "row wrap" with CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a row of a non-fixed number of cells that presents the following properties:

- The cells should only be the size of their content, not more, not less;
- The row should only be the size of its cells (+ gap), not stretch or shrink under any circumstance);
- The row should break lines only when forced by the surrounding layout to prevent an overflow, much like `flex-wrap: row wrap`;
- The row should "force" its size on the surrounding layout as long as nothing overflows (so if the row is brother to a `flex-grow: 1` div, the row shouldn't break its line);
- If possible, all this without setting any style to the cells, and without media queries;

I can do that with `flex` and `row wrap` but I'm wondering if it's possible with `display: grid`.

Here is what I tried :

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 18px 18px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, auto));
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid > * {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaaaa</div>
  <div>aa</div>
  <div>aaaa</div>
</div>
```

That's taking up too much space. Using `auto-fill` makes it shrink too much. How could I do that?

Comment: You can't AFAIK. `autofit` requires at least one "hard" minmax number (0 doesn't count). Frankly, `display:inline-block` would seem to suit your requirements rather than css-grid.

Comment: https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example37/

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes I played a bit around with `auto-fit` vs `auto-fill`, none really seemed to do the trick. So basically there would be `flex` or `inline-block`. I'll stick with `flex` I guess.

Comment: this may probably help you understand the limitation of CSS grid: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55064488/8620333

Comment: This is not an answer but may help understand auto-fit and auto-fill. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129360/css-grid-wrapping.