# Make a grid big enough for its content

Tags: css, grid

I have in my HTML page grids contained in grids contained in grids, all contained in kind of a mother-grid.
It may be ugly but it's a structural requirement of my website.

When the window is small, the grids get smaller as well, and unreadable at one point.

I would like that, when the window gets too small, a single (horizontal) scrollbar appears in order to make the whole readable.

I've read a book about CSS and it didn't give me the answer :(

Any ideas ?

Zlotz

Comment: Maybe `@media` queries will help you https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: It seems that I can do things with @media, but I hoped not to have  to compute the size I need to display my grids. There must be a simpler way, no  ?

Comment: @Zlotz please add your html structure ... or what have you already try ?

Comment: do you have a code snippet to demonstrate your issue and show us how you have set your grid layout (row/colums or area) ? auto-fill/auto-fit could be an option, minmax() or width:min-content could also be another option but also none of this could match what you have done. ...  Answers from the little of your question can be guesses or opinions and maybe you'll be lucky if one of these comes to be efficient... my guess  `display:inline-grid;min-width:100%;`

Comment: My HTML structure is Javascript dependent. The user provokes the creation of grids, and of grids inside grids, and so on.

Comment: please check the answer, if it covers the solution area you were targeting to achieve @Zlotz

Answer (score 1):

Imho, best answer is Christoper's. You can take a look at CSS units here: [CSS Units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) to choose which one fits best for you.

Best choices for your case should be **vw** (relative to viewport width), **%** (relative to parent width) or **em/rem** (relative to font sizes, the first for the current element and the second for the root element)

If you will try **vw** unit, remember to define viewport meta tag on header. In example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

As inferred from the problem statement, please find the below code running for large-screens and small-screen breakpoints, a mother grid containing grids inside grids.... and a single scroll controlling the view of grids in clean manner on smaller screen sizes, screenshots of which have been attached in support of the same.

```css
div{
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 12px;
margin: 0.5px;
}
div.mother-grid{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 350px 350px;

}
div.sub-grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px;
}
div.mother-grid{
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother-grid">
<div class="sub-grid">

<div class="sub-sub-grid">This is sub grid level 2</div>
<div class="sub-sub-grid">This is sub grid level 2</div>
</div>
<div class="sub-grid">

<div class="sub-sub-grid">This is sub grid level 2</div>
<div class="sub-sub-grid">This is sub grid level 2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Specify `min-width` for every cell (of course, depending on the the cell class) rather than for the whole page.  Then effective `min-width` for the whole page will be internally calculated by the layout engine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should specify min-width = what ? "initial" ?

Comment: It depends on what you to display there, initial would be 0.  Minimum width means that if the cell is narrower than that, the display is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using both media queries and possibly auto-fill auto-fit for responsive development.

```
//mobile/tablet portrait
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .inner-grid {
         grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 186px); // you can try
     }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .inner-grid {
     }
}
```

This link might be helpful
[CSS grid wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129360/css-grid-wrapping)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the horizontal scroll bars, you need to make the grid cell scrollable in x axis, use the overflow-x property below. But if you want the children grid not to shrink, either you need to remove the grid layout, or to provide a minimum height and width to the child so that it can create scroll bars.

```
overflow-x : scroll;
```

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use these in css

```
min-width:100px;

//or 

max-width:800px;
```

Comment: I may end up doing this but, depending on the situation, 100px may be not enough

Comment: If it makes me clearer, min-width is variable and I would like to avoid computing it.