# Make flex wrapped elements take less space

Tags: css

When a `display: flex` container has `flex-wrap: wrap` applied the elements still try to take all the available space left. Is there a way to get rid of that extra space on the right of the inner elements or rather the parent element no trying to be 100% of the outer space by default?

As you can see on the image the <- {month} -> could have been narrower if the flex element wasn't trying to take the entire space that's left after the wrap.

[image]

Here's similar case but just made simpler. When you start making the window smaller for the elements to wrap, `calendars`' inner elements take entire width even though they don't have to. What am I missing here? Can the "< January >" block automatically take less space?

```css
.actions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.calendars {
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.no {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="actions">
    <span><</span>
    <span>January</span>
    <span>></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="calendars">
    <div>
      <span class="no">1</span>
      <span class="no">2</span>
      <span class="no">3</span>
      <span class="no">4</span>
      <span class="no">5</span>
      <span class="no">6</span>
      <span class="no">7</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <span class="no">1</span>
      <span class="no">2</span>
      <span class="no">3</span>
      <span class="no">4</span>
      <span class="no">5</span>
      <span class="no">6</span>
      <span class="no">7</span>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Desired outcome
[image]

Comment: That's just the way that wrapping behaves in HTML. The container does not shrink to the minimum width required to fit the wrapped content. There's no option to change this behaviour.

Comment: Yeah looks like the `.calendars` width extends to the edge of the area where wrapping occurs, even with `fit-content`. Doesn't look like what you're after is possible with pure CSS. I could be wrong.

Comment: I've updated my earlier answer to suggest a grid-based solution.

Comment: Another possible set of examples https://stackoverflow.com/q/43129360/125981

Answer (score 2):

Does this grid-based solution do what you need? The key style is to set the `actions` element to span all grid columns.

```
.actions {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

The only limitation I've found with it is that if you have fewer months than will fill the screen horizontally, the actions element will still be too wide.

```js
var m = document.querySelector('.month')
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  m.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', m.cloneNode(true))
```

```css
.d1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 240px);
  gap: 20px;
}

.d1>* {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.actions {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.month {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

.month>div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

.month>div>span {
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">

  <div class="actions">
    <span>&lt;</span>
    <span>January</span>
    <span>&gt;</span>
  </div>

  <div class="month">
    <div>
      <span>1</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
      <span>4</span>
      <span>5</span>
      <span>6</span>
      <span>7</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <span>8</span>
      <span>9</span>
      <span>10</span>
      <span>11</span>
      <span>12</span>
      <span>13</span>
      <span>14</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure you use the **full page** link when running this snippet, then adjust the width of your browser to see how it responds.

EDIT Piggy backing on this solution above:
Consider switch to a grid layout.  Here I show the 7 days in a week in `a-row` for the CSS and then only have to put the correct number of blanks at the start.

```css
* {
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent-container {
  display: grid;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.calendar-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 13em);
  grid-template-rows: auto-fill;
  justify-content: center;
}

.calendar-month {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.25em;
  border: solid 1px green;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 0.25em;
}

.actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  justify-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.actions .buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 0.25em;
}

.actions .action-title {
  color: blue;
}

.actions .buttons button {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  padding-left: 0.25em;
  padding-right: 0.25em;
}

.calendar-month .cal-days {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1.5em);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1.25em);
  gap: 0.25em;
  place-items: center;
}

.no {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="calendar-container">
    <div class="calendar-month">
      <div class="actions">
        <div class="buttons">
          <button type="button">Today</button>
          <button type="button">Tomorrow</button>
          <button type="button">In 2 days</button>
        </div>
        <div class="action-title">January 2023</div>
      </div>
      <div class="cal-days">
        <span class="no">1</span>
        <span class="no">2</span>
        <span class="no">3</span>
        <span class="no">4</span>
        <span class="no">5</span>
        <span class="no">6</span>
        <span class="no">7</span>
        <span class="no">8</span>
        <span class="no">9</span>
        <span class="no">10</span>
        <span class="no">11</span>
        <span class="no">12</span>
        <span class="no">13</span>
        <span class="no">14</span>
        <span class="no">15</span>
        <span class="no">16</span>
        <span class="no">17</span>
        <span class="no">18</span>
        <span class="no">19</span>
        <span class="no">20</span>
        <span class="no">21</span>
        <span class="no">22</span>
        <span class="no">23</span>
        <span class="no">24</span>
        <span class="no">25</span>
        <span class="no">26</span>
        <span class="no">27</span>
        <span class="no">29</span>
        <span class="no">30</span>
        <span class="no">31</span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-month">
      <div class="actions">
        <div class="buttons"></div>
        <div class="action-title">February</div>
      </div>
      <div class="cal-days">
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no">1</span>
        <span class="no">2</span>
        <span class="no">3</span>
        <span class="no">4</span>
        <span class="no">5</span>
        <span class="no">6</span>
        <span class="no">7</span>
        <span class="no">8</span>
        <span class="no">9</span>
        <span class="no">10</span>
        <span class="no">11</span>
        <span class="no">12</span>
        <span class="no">16</span>
        <span class="no">13</span>
        <span class="no">14</span>
        <span class="no">15</span>
        <span class="no">16</span>
        <span class="no">17</span>
        <span class="no">18</span>
        <span class="no">19</span>
        <span class="no">20</span>
        <span class="no">21</span>
        <span class="no">22</span>
        <span class="no">23</span>
        <span class="no">24</span>
        <span class="no">25</span>
        <span class="no">26</span>
        <span class="no">27</span>
        <span class="no">28</span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-month">
      <div class="actions">
        <div class="action-title">Bearanary</div>
      </div>
      <div class="cal-days">
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no">1</span>
        <span class="no">2</span>
        <span class="no">3</span>
        <span class="no">4</span>
        <span class="no">6</span>
        <span class="no">7</span>
        <span class="no">8</span>
        <span class="no">9</span>
        <span class="no">10</span>
        <span class="no">11</span>
        <span class="no">12</span>
        <span class="no">13</span>
        <span class="no">14</span>
        <span class="no">15</span>
        <span class="no">16</span>
        <span class="no">17</span>
        <span class="no">18</span>
        <span class="no">19</span>
        <span class="no">20</span>
        <span class="no">21</span>
        <span class="no">22</span>
        <span class="no">23</span>
        <span class="no">24</span>
        <span class="no">25</span>
        <span class="no">26</span>
        <span class="no">27</span>
        <span class="no">29</span>
        <span class="no">30</span>
        <span class="no">31</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-month">
      <div class="actions">
        <div class="action-title">Fishly</div>
      </div>
      <div class="cal-days">
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no"></span>
        <span class="no">1</span>
        <span class="no">2</span>
        <span class="no">3</span>
        <span class="no">4</span>
        <span class="no">6</span>
        <span class="no">7</span>
        <span class="no">8</span>
        <span class="no">9</span>
        <span class="no">10</span>
        <span class="no">11</span>
        <span class="no">12</span>
        <span class="no">13</span>
        <span class="no">14</span>
        <span class="no">15</span>
        <span class="no">16</span>
        <span class="no">17</span>
        <span class="no">18</span>
        <span class="no">19</span>
        <span class="no">20</span>
        <span class="no">21</span>
        <span class="no">22</span>
        <span class="no">23</span>
        <span class="no">24</span>
        <span class="no">25</span>
        <span class="no">26</span>
        <span class="no">27</span>
        <span class="no">29</span>
        <span class="no">30</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Week will always be under another week, what I am trying to accomplish is one next to the other until wrapped and then take only as much space as a calendar takes, hence the `flex`, `flex-wrap`.

Comment: Yes, so you always want the weeks underneath each other, but you want the **months** to be displayed next to each other unless there is insufficient space. I have updated the snippet in my answer to include an additional month, so you can see how that would work.

Comment: There should only be 1 actions bar - staying at the width of either 2 calendars next to each other or 1 when they are stacked on top of each other. The weeks were just a mock for a month calendar. Say if there's 2 months it will be < Jan - Feb > or something like that. There shouldn't be 2 action bars and that's the tricky bit. It needs to stay the width of either 2 calendars or 1 when stacked.

Comment: Check out the desired outcome image in the post.

Comment: I have modified my answer to suggest a grid-based solution.

Comment: I hope you do not mind but I added a SECOND example to your answer following on the same theme of a grid - I also added CSS to show how the rows (calendar days) can wrap by just putting the right number of blank days at the start by using the 7 repeated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the available tools in CSS for automatic width can't exactly handle it the way you want. When using a wrapping content, either with simple inline text or with flex wrapping, there're 3 relevant automatic width modes:

- `stretch` which takes the full width of the container.
- `max-content` which disables the wrapping and takes as much horizontal space as needed.
- `min-content` which *always* wrap so you can as well just use `flex-direction: column`

True, there's also `fit-content` which smartly switches between the other modes (it's actually an alias for `min(max-content, max(min-content, stretch))`[1]), but it does no recursive logic, means it doesn't say "alright if `max-content` turns out to be wider than `stretch` then I'll go to `min-content`".

It's algorithm picks `stretch` unless even `min-content` is wider than `stretch` or unless even `max-content` is smaller than `stretch`, so it doesn't really help if you want to exactly fit wrapped content.

The best I can suggest you is give the wrapping up and instead use a grid to define the number of columns based on a media query (perhaps there's a way to fit it automatically with grid but I failed to find one).

```css
.actions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.calendars {
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;
  gap: 24px;
  background: blue;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .calendars {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

.no {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="actions">
    <span><</span>
    <span>January</span>
    <span>></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="calendars">
    <div>
      <span class="no">1</span>
      <span class="no">2</span>
      <span class="no">3</span>
      <span class="no">4</span>
      <span class="no">5</span>
      <span class="no">6</span>
      <span class="no">7</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <span class="no">1</span>
      <span class="no">2</span>
      <span class="no">3</span>
      <span class="no">4</span>
      <span class="no">5</span>
      <span class="no">6</span>
      <span class="no">7</span>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

[1] https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#valdef-width-fit-content