# CSS grids and shrink priority

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to use a CSS grid for the main layout of my application and I am struggling to find to right formula

Here is the structure of the design I want to achieve (Stackbliz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-umasjm?file=style.css))

[image]

- The whole design should fill the space horizontally
- The **main** part (in green) contains a text that cannot be wrapped
- the **aside** part (in blue) contains some random text. I would like it to have a **min-with** of **200px**  and **max-width** of **300px**

Here are the rules that I try to implement :

- On extra large screens : the **aside** part should have a width of **300px** and the **main** part should take the remaining space
- If there is not enough space to display the title entirely, the **aside** part should shrink in priority, down to **200px**
- If there is still not enough space for the title to be displayed entirely, the **aside** part should have a width of **200px** and the **main** part should display a **text-ellipsis** on the title

Up to now, I have this :

```css
#grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;

  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 100%) minmax(200px, 300px);
  grid-template-areas: 'area-main area-aside';
}

main {
  grid-area: area-main;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  padding: 1rem;
}

main h1 {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

aside {
  grid-area: area-aside;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

The result I get is almost correct except that the **aside** part does not shrink to 200px

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS grid wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129360/css-grid-wrapping)

Comment: @TylerH I read it but I did not understand how it solves the problem. Here, I just want to have 2 sections, I don't want to repeat elements 

Comment: How about flex instead and min- and max-widths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet uses flex instead of grid - allowing the second element to grow to fill the remaining width but ensuring that width is never more than 300px or less than 200px by setting the min and max widths of the first element to 100% (of the wrapper width) minus 300px and 200px respectively.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: pink;
}

main {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-width: calc(100% - 300px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

main h1 {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

aside {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-wrapper">
  <main>
    <h1>Very long title that cannot be wrapped</h1>
  </main>
  <aside>
    min-width: 200px;
    <br>max-width: 300px;
  </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[fit-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content_function) and min-width might be what you are looking for :

example:

```css
section {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto fit-content(300px);
  margin-bottom:.5em;
}
article {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  padding: 1rem;
}

aside {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  min-width:200px;
}
/* show me where aside stands with the 0-300px range */
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:1em 0;
  background:linear-gradient(to left,silver 200px,  gray 200px 300px, white 300px);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    article
  </article>
  <aside>
    aside
  </aside>
</section>
<section>
  <article>
    article
  </article>
  <aside>
    an aside a bit longer than the other one
  </aside>
</section>
<section>
  <article>
    article
  </article>
  <aside>
    an aside a bit much longer than the other one
  </aside>
</section>
```